# Xamarin Android complete action with

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, intentfilter

I have created an app which is almost finished. 
When browsing your files using Samsung MyFiles app or whatever, you have to be able to click on a file and open the "complete action with/open with" dialog with my app in the list of available apps. How do I get my app in that list?

Can someone help by pointing me in the right direction at least?

Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter (new string[] {Intent.ActionView}, 
              Categories=new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },  
              DataScheme="file", 
              DataHost="*", 
              DataMimeType="*/*", 
              DataPathPattern=".*\\\\.abc")]  

public class MainActivity : Activity 
{
  your activity's code here...
}
```

Where **.abc** is the file extension you want to open with your app.